# Java How to get collection(List) of specific values in JsonObject contains a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, gson

I am new to Java and I have a javabeans conatins

```
class Players{
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

@SerializedName("teamOne")
@Expose
private List<TeamOne> teamOne;

@SerializedName("teamTwo")
@Expose
private List<TeamTwo> teamTwo;

public String getStatus() {return status);}
public void setStatus(String status) {this.status = status;}

public List<TeamOne> getTeamOne(){ return teamOne:}
public setTeamOne(List<TeamOne> teamOne){ this.teamOne= teamOne:}

public List<TeamTwo> getTeamTwo(){ return teamTwo:}
public setTeamTwo(List<TeamTwo> teamTwo){ this.teamTwo= teamTwo;}

}

class TeamOne {
 @SerializedName("winningScore")
@Expose
private String winningScore;

@SerializedName("playerName")
@Expose
private String PlayerName;
}

class TeamTwo {
 @SerializedName("winningScore")
@Expose
private String winningScore;

@SerializedName("playerName")
@Expose
private String PlayerName;
}
```

My json return looks like

```
{
"status":"BestPlayers",
"teamOne":[
   {
   "winningScore":"11",
   "playerName":"John"
   },
   {
   "winningScore":"11",
   "playerName":"David"
   }
],
"teamTwo":[
  {
   "winningScore":"15",
   "playerName":"Victor"
  },
 {
  "winningScore":"15",
  "playerName":"Thomas"
  }
]
}
```

Now I am trying to get List of the players Name in both teams.
which should look [John, David, Victor,Thomas]

I tried a while loop which could loop what ever the number on arrays but could not do that, but am getting only the first players name and thats it, I could not even reach to the second team array. I would really appreciate your help.

need help with this code

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your POJO Model class its should be `TeamDetails` or `Team`

```
    class Players{
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("teamOne")
    @Expose
    private List<Team> teamOne;

    @SerializedName("teamTwo")
    @Expose
    private List<Team> teamTwo;
}


  class Team {
     @SerializedName("winningScore")
    @Expose
    private String winningScore;

    @SerializedName("playerName")
    @Expose
    private String PlayerName;
    }
```

now create a Final List of players like

```
private getTotalList(){
    List<Team> finalTeams=new ArrayList()
if(null!=teamOne && teamOne.size()>0){ // thats how your requirment will work
    finalTeams.add(teamOne)
}
//same goes for all teams add null check and add them.
 if(null!=teamTwo && teamTwo .size()>0){ // thats how your requirment will work
    finalTeams.add(teamTwo)
}



if(null!=funLovers && funLovers .size()>0){ 
        finalTeams.add(funLovers)
    }

        return finalTeams:
     }
```

then use foreach loop

```
for(Team  team: finalTeams){
Log.d("playerName: ", team.PlayerName)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Atif AbbAsi ,for you prompt reply. but my problem is those teamOne and teamTwo can come in different ways like "FunLovers" , HokeyPlayers, but the winningscore and PlayerName are always there, I need to catch and save the playerNames in a list no matter the object thats holds it, in this case lets say instead of teamOne and teamTwo , if it comes teamTwo and funLovers I can use to loops if neseccary but could not figure that out. Thank you Again

Comment: @Bxihit then add all possible object and check if funlover is not null and its size is greater than zero add it. all you have to so is check if value is not null add them to list.